# Pyspark Dataframes as View

Tags: sql, view, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

For a script that I am running, I have a bunch of chained views that looked at a specific set of data in sql (I am using Apache Spark SQL):

```
%sql
create view view_1 as
select column_1,column_2 from original_data_table
```

This logic culminates in `view_n`.
However, I then need to perform logic that is difficult (or impossible) to implement in sql, specifically, the `explode` command:

```
%python
df_1 = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * from view_n")
df1_exploded=df_1.withColumn("exploded_column", explode(split(df_1f.col_to_explode,',')))
```

## My Questions:

1. Is there a speed cost associated with switching to and from sql tables to pyspark dataframes? Or, since pyspark dataframes are lazily evaluated, is it very similair to a view?
2. Is there a better way of switching from and sql table to a pyspark dataframe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `explode()` and just about anything that DF has via Spark SQL (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html)

```py
print(spark.version)
2.4.3

df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, [1,2,3]), (2, [4,5,6]), (3, [7,8,9]),],["id", "nest"])
df.printSchema()

root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- nest: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)

df.createOrReplaceTempView("sql_view")
spark.sql("SELECT id, explode(nest) as un_nest FROM sql_view").show()

df.createOrReplaceTempView("sql_view")
spark.sql("SELECT id, explode(nest) as flatten FROM sql_view").show()

+---+-------+
| id|flatten|
+---+-------+
|  1|      1|
|  1|      2|
|  1|      3|
|  2|      4|
|  2|      5|
|  2|      6|
|  3|      7|
|  3|      8|
|  3|      9|
+---+-------+
```

Comment: I did not know that! Thanks. However, if I want to use pyspark, do you know how I could do so on a view that was created with Spark SQL?

Comment: sure ... ```df = spark.sql("sql from view here")``` ... a view is just sql query being called usually from a persisted object like a table to display some aggregations/KPIs so to my knowledge you would just have to read in the view's sql string as df, but best to keep the view as just sql and not df so you aren't duplicating objects and having to promote new views from dfs because it creates too many dependencies